# Input reset in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I am working on a react app. Where I am talking a two inputs in form after submitting the form my fields are not reseting. How to do those. I am attaching my form component code can anyone help me out with this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.getWeather}>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city.." />
            <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="country.." /><br></br>
            <button >Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `getWeather` method you will have access the React synthetic event object, say `event`. Get the native dom element out of it using `event.target`, and then call the [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method as `event.target.reset()`. This will clear all the form input values.

Play with the below example.

```js
function App() {
  const onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.reset();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Enter your name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Reset!" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Or alternatively set a ref on the form and call the reset method as described

Comment: @RossMackay When `form` in the child component, `ref` will be too much work.. So getting it out of the `event` object is much easier IMO.

Comment: Either way the `getWeather` function should probably be oblivious to the form logic. You might want to grab the field data and reset the form in an intermediary function like Arup's example and have getWeather only handle the city/country args

Comment: By using e.target.reset(); in getWeather function in a main component worked. Thanks @ArupRakshit

Comment: Thanks @RossMackay